A relation about norms of a block matrix.
Suppose $M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 A & B \\
 B^{T} & C \\
\end{bmatrix}$,
where $A$ and $C$ are $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices and $B$ is an arbitrary $n\times n$ real matrix. By calculating some examples about $A, B$ and $C$ by Matlab, I found there may be an interesting relation as follows. $$|M|^{2} = |A|^{2} + 2|B|^{2} + |C|^{2}.$$
Here $|A|^{2}$ denotes the sum of square of singular values of a matrix $A$. If $A$ is symmetric, $|A|^{2}$ is clearly the sum of square of eigenvalues of $A$.
If $n = 1$, the relation above is absolutely true. In this case, $M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 a & b \\
 b & c \\
\end{bmatrix}$ for some real numbers $a, b$ and $c$. Suppose $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ are eigenvalues of $M$, then
\begin{align*}
 |M|^{2} 
 & = \lambda_{1}^{2} + \lambda_{2}^{2} = (\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2})^{2} - 2\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2} \\
 & = (a + c)^{2} - 2(ac - b^2) = a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2.
\end{align*}
My question is that, if $n > 1$, does the relation above still hold true?

It is the Frobenius norm

@Saiba The answer is yes. Note that
$$
|A|^2 = \sum_j \sigma_j^2(A) = \sum_{j = 1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ij}^2
$$
